# Array of coordinates, go from 0 to last

Tags: javascript

Hello everyone i am wondering if it's possible to loop throught an array of coordinates so i can do some action asynchronous on every coordinate?

I mean i have a player object:

```js
var player = {
  name: "Example",
  x: 21,
  y: 20,
  go: function(x, y) {
    console.log("Walking");
    //Obviously heres a walking scripting but too much code
  }
}



function goToCordinates(data) {
  data.map(function(cord) {
      var i = setInterval(() => {
          if (!(Math.abs(player.x - cord.x) <= 1 && Math.abs(player.y - cord.y) <= 1)) {
            //player.go(cord.x, cord.y);
          } else {
              clearInterval(i);
            //Player on coordinates
          }
      }, 1000);
  }); 
};


goToCordinates([
  {x: 11, y: 21},
  {x: 12, y: 11},
  {x: 24, y: 26},
]);
```

Inside the goToCordinates() im checking using inveral if my player.x and player.y are 1 field away from that coordinates. If yes, it finishes. (The code i've shoved you is obviously wrong. Because there are 3 ouputs in goToCordinates. Basically i want to grab the first x, y, check if player is on these cordinates, then grab second one (somehow), and force him to ho to these coordinates with player.go(x, y) once again. And repeat that, untlil it match the last data in array. It's also really important that i will automatically check whats' the lenght of the array, and how much "checkpoints" it has to force a player to go.

Anoyone can help? :/

Comment: Why do you want to go 1 unit away, rather than exactly on the location?

Comment: Please keep your question after it has been answered so others can see benefit from it

Answer (score 0):

Process the queue as a spaced-out for loop. Store the current index, and treat each interval as an iteration of the loop.

```
function goToCordinates(data) {
      var index = 0;
      var i = setInterval(() => {
          let coord = data[index];
          if (!(Math.abs(player.x - coord.x) <= 1 && Math.abs(player.y - coord.y) <= 1)) {
            //player.move(coord.x, coord.y);
          } else {
              if (i < data.length) i++;
              else clearInterval(i);
            //Player on coordinates
          }
      }, 1000);
  }); 
};
```